# Python: converting a tuple to a string representation

Tags: python

I am writing a function volumes that takes the numerical representation of a partitioning of a phone book. If the argument passed to the function does not represent a valid numerical representation of a partitioning of a phone book, the function raise an AssertionError with the message invalid partitioning. Otherwise, the function must return the string representation of the given partitioning.

With my code I still didn't solve the following cases:
1. volumes('A-D E-J K-O P-Z') which must raise an Assertion Error
2. volumes(42) which must raise an Assertion Error
3. volumes((1, 10, 1, 12, 1, 1)) which must return `'A B-K L M-X Y Z'` in stead of 
`'A B-K L M-X Y Z-Z'` which is the case with my code

Can anyone help me?

```
def volumes(seq):
    '''
    >>> volumes((4, 6, 5, 11))
    'A-D E-J K-O P-Z'
    >>> volumes((7, 8, 1, 10))
    'A-G H-O P Q-Z'
    >>> volumes((4, 7, 5, 10))
    'A-D E-K L-P Q-Z'
    >>> volumes((8, 3, 9, 7))
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    AssertionError: invalid partitioning
    '''
    if type(seq) is tuple:
        import itertools
        q = list(itertools.accumulate(seq))


    if type(seq) is tuple:
        assert "invalid partitioning" 

    assert (sum(x for x in seq) == 26), "invalid partitioning"
    assert q[-1] == 26, "invalid partitioning" 
    assert seq[-1] != 0, "invalid partitioning"  
    assert seq[-1] > 0, "invalid partitioning" 

    st = 'A'
    count = 0

    for x in seq:
        count += int(x)
        new = count + 64
        if int(x) < 2 and new < 90:
            st = st + " " + chr(new+1)
        elif int(x) >= 2 and new < 90:
            st = st + "-" + chr(new) + " " + chr(new+1)
        else:
            st = st + "-" + chr(new)

    return st
```

Comment: This is not a code-writing site. Please tell us what you have tried, what happens and what you would expect.

Comment: volumes((1, 10, 1, 12, 1, 1)) must return 'A B-K L M-X Y Z' as a string representation. Now it returns 'A B-K L M-X Y Z-Z'. I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the last part of your code to allow for the special case when the final digit is 1:

```
for x in seq:
    count += int(x)
    new = count + 64
    if int(x) < 2 and new < 90:
        st = st + " " + chr(new+1)
    elif int(x) >= 2 and new < 90:
        st = st + "-" + chr(new) + " " + chr(new+1)
    elif int(x)<2 and new == 90:
        st = st
    else:
        st = st + "-" + chr(new)

return st
```